# How to handle non-HTTP 200 responses nicely with promisified request

Tags: javascript, node.js, request, promise

Using the promisfied request:

```
const request = Promise.promisify(require('request'));
Promise.promisifyAll(request);


request('http://google.com').spread(function(res, body) {
}).catch(function(e) {
  // does not get hit on HTTP 404
});
```

This works nicely, unfortunately the error block with `catch` is not hit on non-HTTP 200 as one might expect. Is there a way to change the behavior, so that the block gets triggered?

Maybe something like

```
if (res.statusCode !== 200) { reject(res) }
```

not sure. In a way it makes sense, because it's proper response and not necessarily an unforseen event, but I would like to make clean use of Promises for better readability.

Comment: You may want to take a look at [http-as-promised](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-as-promised) as it will do that for you. You can even [catch specific HTTP statuses](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-as-promised#catching-http-errors) using Bluebird's `.catch()` predicate.

Comment: Thanks, I will use [request-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise) instead.